# Why $L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

After the characterisation theorem for a $F \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$, i.e.

> $H^{-1}$ is the set of distributions such that $F= f_0 + \operatorname{div}(\boldsymbol{f})$, with $f_0 \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\boldsymbol{f}=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ a vector of $L^2$ functions. Also, $$||F||_{H^{-1}} \leq C_P ||f_0||_0 + ||\boldsymbol{f}||_0$$

my professor wrote that $$L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$$ **I don't know if I can show this, and especially how I should move.**

I think I should prove that $$||F||_{H^{-1}} \leq ||F||_{L^2}$$ where both norms are dual norms.

Here's what I tried:

---

Now, $$||F||_{H^{-1}} = \sup \{|Fv|, v\in H^1_0, ||v||_1 \leq 1  \}$$ and $$||F||_{L^{2}} = \sup \{|Fv|, v\in L^2, ||v||_0 \leq 1  \}$$ Since $H_0^1 (\Omega) \subset H^1(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$

then in the $||F||_{L^2}$ I'm taking the supremum over a larger set, so it should be bigger than $||F||_{H^{-1}}$, right?

Comment: What is the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_0$ norm?

Comment: @KeeleyHoek the norm induced by the $L^2$ scalar product. While $||v||_1 = (\nabla v, \nabla v)$

Comment: So $\lVert \cdot \rVert_0 = \lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^2}$?

Comment: Yes @KeeleyHoek

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking things. By your characterization, taking $F = f_0$ you know that $\lVert F \rVert_{H^{-1}} = \lVert f_0 \rVert_{H^{-1}} \leq C_P\lVert f_0 \rVert_0$. This exactly means that the inclusion $L^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$ is bounded with norm at most $C_P$.

Comment: Why are you allowed to take $F=f_0$, without considering the divergence part? @KeeleyHoek

Comment: @bobinthebox The characterization as stated means that each $F \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ determines and is determined by a choice of $f_0 \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\mathbf{f} \in L^2(\Omega)^n$. We are just restricting to the subset of elements of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ for which $\mathbf{f} = (0, \ldots, 0)$.

Comment: Okay, I got this. One last thing: why does $\lVert f_0 \rVert_{H^{-1}} \leq C_P\lVert f_0 \rVert_0$ implies the inclusion is bounded? That's what I don't really get. I would expect to see again $F$ on the r.h.s. of the inequality, but you have $f_0$. That's confusing me. After this issue, I am okay

Comment: Let's give the inclusion a name: view it as the function $i : L^2(\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega)$ which maps any $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ to its associated distribution $i(f)$, which in turn by the characterization in your question statement is an element of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Then by definition $i$ (which of course is itself a linear map) is bounded if there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ we have $\lVert i(f) \rVert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \leq C \lVert f \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$. But of course your characterization result implies that such a $C$ exists: take $C = C_P$.

Comment: Hopefully this clears up your confusion about the notation, and how we do not need to use the particular notation $F$ or $f_0$.